# How to compare strings with not exact matching

Tags: python, data-science, string-comparison, speech-to-text

I need to compare two output strings namely the original transcription and a transcription of a Speech-to-Text service. Often numbers are written in a numerical format or as a word e.g. "four" or "4". How to compare strings considering these different methods of transcribing?

So far I just transformed both strings in lower case letters and split each word with a space as seperator.

```
#Read the two files and store them in s1_raw and s2_raw
with open('original.txt', 'r') as f:
    s1_raw = f.read()
with open('comparison.txt', 'r') as f:
    s2_raw = f.read()

#Transform all letters to minuscule letter
s1 = s1_raw.lower()
s2 = s2_raw.lower()

#Split texts with space as seperator to have a list of words
s1_set = s1.split(' ')
s2_set = s2.split(' ')

#Used later for confidence calculation
count1 = len(s1_set)
count2 = 0
x = 0

#Check which string is longer to prevent running out of indices
if len(s1_set) < len(s2_set):
    #Loop through whole list and compare word by word
    for x in range (0, len(s1_set)):
        if s1_set[x] == s2_set[x]:
            count2 += 1
        x += 1
else:
    #Loop through whole list and compare word by word
    for x in range (0, len(s2_set)):
        if s1_set[x] == s2_set[x]:
            count2 += 1
        x += 1

#Confidence level= correct words divided by total words
confidence = count2/count1

#Print out result
print('The confidence level of this service is {:.2f}%'.format(confidence*100))
```

I want to measure the accuracy of the transcription for several *.txt files and consider all the different ways of how the different Speech-to-Text services transcribe.

Comment: Perhaps this might help? https://pypi.org/project/word2number/. It works both ways too.

Comment: Take a look at NLP techniques like in https://monkeylearn.com/blog/beginners-guide-text-vectorization/

Comment: @Reez0: thanks, I will for sure use that function. If not for this task then another time!

Comment: @B.Go: Also thanks for pointing out that cool method but how could I apply it for this task. If I just count the different words in that context and have a match, it doesn't mean that the sense of the transcription is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have to normalize the text before comparing it. First decide if `four` or `4` is your canonical form and convert all strings to that form.

For example, if `four` is the canonical form, then write code to replace `1` with `one`, `213` with `two hundred and thirteen`, and so on, and do the comparison with these.

Actually, I think that it is better to normalize to `4` rather than `four` since there can be more than one way to express a number in some languages. By preferring `4` it is possible to normalize all equivalent transcriptions to one single form.

Comment: Thanks Michael
Is there a python module to do that easily or will I have to do that for all the numbers myself?
What about the problem if some sentences are misunderstood and thus the number of words per sentence differs from the original one?

Comment: @Parleoth I guess there should be some module somewhere to do that. Couple months ago, out of curiosity, I scanned Lucene (Java) for an analyzer that does something like that, but could not find any. I'd search for natural language parsing/understanding modules. This are slightly more difficult with fractions: 1.5 gallons = a gallon and a half, or 2.75 pieces = two pieces and three quarters

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Michael Veksler. I tried the NLTK library now to split the string into word lists more efficiently. Also, I tried to look for synonyms of each word and compare if the synonyms match. This still doesn't really solve the task so I wonder what else I could try.

I use those two libraries:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
```

Splitting the words is as easy as:

```
s1_set = word_tokenize(list1)
```

Now I try to find synonyms of the words and take the first found synonym. I append it to an empty list named "wl1". I check before, if any synonym is found, since this is not always the case.

```
for i in range(0, (len(s1_set)-1)):
    #Find synonym of word in s1_set index i
    t1 = wordnet.synsets(s1_set[i])
    #Ensure t1 isn't empty
    if t1:
        wl1.append(t1[0].lemmas()[0].name())
```

Then I am again comparing word by word like in my first post above. This method isn't a satisfying solution to my problem either.
Can anyone think of a better method?